# What is the name of the process for angular 2 ng serve?

Tags: macos, angular-cli

I start the angular-cli (angular 2) application with the command

```
ng serve &
```

How to kill this process, I do not see any ng or npm or node in the process list?
I run on macOS

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the @angular/cli process and kill it. I'm not sure what are the side effects (if there's any) but it kills the server running on 4200.

just giving an example for further reference:

$ ps aux | grep angular

host  4904  1.2  2.2 1508916 371760 pts/2  Sl   19:03   0:23 @angular/cli

$ kill 4904

This should do the job!

Thanks :)

Comment: This answer might need to be updated to change `angular` to `ng` in the command and the command line output